# Arcgis javascript api: Typeerror: l is not a constructor. Only happens after minification

Tags: reactjs, arcgis

Using "@arcgis/core": "^4.20.2",

Turning on a layer:

```
  if (layerId != null) {
    const layer = (mapView as any).map?.layers?.items?.find((layer) => layer.id === layerId);
    layer.visible = true;
  }
```

Works locally.

But in production, the minified version gives  Typeerror: l is not a constructor.

[image]

What can be wrong? Bug in minification process?

Using Create React App from a few years ago.